# Print each record of output in separate lines in python using boto3

Tags: python, python-3.x, boto3

I have data from a table stored in a local .csv file. I have uploaded the file to s3 using:

```
import boto3
s3_object = boto3.client('s3',region_name='region name',aws_access_key_id='access key',aws_secret_access_key='secret key)
s3_object.put_object(Body='', Bucket='bucket',Key='folder name')
#s3_object.upload_file("source file name",'bucket','target folder/file name')
```

I am querying the S3 folder as:

```
import boto3
s3_object = boto3.client('s3',region_name='region name',aws_access_key_id='access key',aws_secret_access_key='secret key)
content = s3_object.get_object(Bucket='bucket',Key='target folder/file name')
result = content['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
for line in result:
    print(line)
```

The source data is like:

```
Name,Address,Sex,Id
John,USA,M,123
Peter,,M,34
,USA,F,35
```

I am getting the output as:

```
N
a
m
e
,
A
d
d
r
e
s
s
,
S
e
x
,
I
d

J
o
h
n
,
U
S
A
,
M
,
1
2
3

P
e
t
e
r
```

like this.....

What is the way to get the output just like source file...

Answer (score 1):

instead of writing

```
for line in result:
    print(line)
```

try just

```
print(result)
```

Does this work?